# Using Variables and/or Properties with Simple Data Writer in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Using JMeter v5.1.1, I am setting a dynamic file path and name to be used with Simple Data Writer.  I've tried this every way I can think of to no avail.  Things I've tried:

- JSR223 PreProcessor (scoped to same thread group) which stores dynamic path/name in variables, and use variable in Simple Data Writer
- Execute thread groups consecutively.  Use StartUp Thread with JSR223 Sampler which stores dynamic path/name in properties, and use `__P` function in Simple Data Writer to retrieve path/name.  This method will pull the property values from the previous run if I do not remove the properties at the end of the test.
- Execute thread groups consecutively.  Use StartUp Thread with JSR223 Sampler which stores dynamic path/name in properties.  Run JSR223 PreProcessor which stores global properties as variables in thread group, and use variables in Simple Data Writer to retrieve path/name.  I've also tried the `__V` function with this approach.  This method will pull the property values from the previous run if I do not remove the properties at the end of the test.

I can see in the JSR223 scripts that the path/name are being set correctly using `log.info`.  I can also see them set when using a debug sampler, but for some reason the Simple Data Writer does not seem to be picking them up.  If I set the variables before running, it works fine.  This seems like an order of operations problem, or asynchronous/multi-thread issue, but am not sure how to proceed.  Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Here's a sample to reproduce the behavior:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.1.1 r1855137">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Data Writer Issue" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">true</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <SetupThreadGroup guiclass="SetupThreadGroupGui" testclass="SetupThreadGroup" testname="setUp Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </SetupThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <JSR223Sampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JSR223Sampler" testname="Set Path to Store Results" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="scriptLanguage">groovy</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="parameters"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="cacheKey">true</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="script">import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

// Get the separator for current OS
String separator = File.separator;

// Use {{current directory}}/csv for path
String path = FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + separator + &quot;csv&quot; + separator;

// Create directory if doesn&apos;t already exist
(new File(path)).mkdirs();

log.info(path);

// Save path to property
props.put(&quot;data-file-path&quot;, path);</stringProp>
        </JSR223Sampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <JSR223Sampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JSR223Sampler" testname="Set FileName to Store Results" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="scriptLanguage">groovy</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="parameters"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="cacheKey">true</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="script">import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; 
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

// Get current date/time formatted as yyyyMMddHHmm
String formattedDateTime = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(&quot;yMMddHHmm&quot;));

// Get name of currently-running script
String scriptName = FileServer.getFileServer().getScriptName();

// Save fileName as scriptName (minus file extension) with timestamp at end
String fileName = scriptName.take(scriptName.lastIndexOf(&apos;.&apos;))  + &quot;_&quot; + formattedDateTime + &quot;.csv&quot;;

log.info(fileName);

// Set filename as property
props.put(&quot;data-file-name&quot;, fileName);</stringProp>
        </JSR223Sampler>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Sample GET Requests" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">2</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.delayedStart">true</boolProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <DebugSampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugSampler" testname="Debug Sampler" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
        </DebugSampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="SimpleDataWriter" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="Save Results to CSV File" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
          <objProp>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>false</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
              <bytes>true</bytes>
              <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
              <url>true</url>
              <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
              <idleTime>true</idleTime>
              <connectTime>true</connectTime>
            </value>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename">${__P(data-file-path)}${__P(data-file-name)}</stringProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
        <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="Get ToDo" enabled="true">
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">jsonplaceholder.typicode.com</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">https</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/todos/1</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments">&quot;groupNames&quot;: [&quot;${__P(GroupNames_${__Random(1,${__property(GroupNames_matchNr)})})}&quot;]</stringProp>
        </HTTPSamplerProxy>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
      <PostThreadGroup guiclass="PostThreadGroupGui" testclass="PostThreadGroup" testname="tearDown Thread Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </PostThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <JSR223Sampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="JSR223Sampler" testname="Clear Dynamic Properties" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="scriptLanguage">groovy</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="parameters"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="cacheKey">true</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="script">props.remove(&quot;data-file-path&quot;);
props.remove(&quot;data-file-name&quot;);</stringProp>
        </JSR223Sampler>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
      <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="true">
        <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
        <objProp>
          <name>saveConfig</name>
          <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
            <time>true</time>
            <latency>true</latency>
            <timestamp>true</timestamp>
            <success>true</success>
            <label>true</label>
            <code>true</code>
            <message>true</message>
            <threadName>true</threadName>
            <dataType>true</dataType>
            <encoding>false</encoding>
            <assertions>true</assertions>
            <subresults>true</subresults>
            <responseData>false</responseData>
            <samplerData>false</samplerData>
            <xml>false</xml>
            <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
            <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
            <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
            <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
            <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
            <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
            <bytes>true</bytes>
            <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
            <url>true</url>
            <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
            <idleTime>true</idleTime>
            <connectTime>true</connectTime>
          </value>
        </objProp>
        <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
      </ResultCollector>
      <hashTree/>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can debug this issue using step-by-step Debugger. Also you can use inbuilt JMeter function to complete your requirement if you can. Because inbuilt JMeter function works well in listener's path.

Comment: Can you provide an example of using "inbuilt JMeter function"?

Comment: Example-  Result_${__time(ddMMYY-HHmmss,)}.csv

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in the [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer)'s filename field, in fact you can, but it will return default value of `1` so when you run your test file with the name of `11` is being generated in the folder where you run your tests from and this is where your results go.

In general you [should not be using Listeners for anything but tests development and/or debugging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) because they don't add any value and just consuming valuable system resources. [Neither you should run your test in GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)

Assuming above points I would recommend reconsidering your approach and use `-l` command-line argument to specify the .jtl results file location. If you want to add timestamp for this - go for operating system [date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/date) and [time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/time) commands, for example:

- Windows:

  ```
  jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l csv/%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.csv
  ```
- Unix and derivatives:

  ```
  jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l csv/`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.csv
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the information!  I thought using the Simple Data Writer listener was the recommended approach when running tests in CLI.